# Calculate specific result by numeric series multiplication and their later sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

firstly I need to apologize for my non mathematical language.
Secondly I'll try to explain what I would like to calculate:

I have 3 series/rows of numbers and every series has 5 numbers(for example):

1.series:   2,4,9,1,7

2.series:   3,1,8,6,2

3.series:   8,0,6,0,9

sum of their columns should be as close as possible to this result:

result:     90,60,70,21,45

any series may/may not be multiplied by any multiplier

Could someone advice me what method shall be used for the calculation please?
Any help is greatly appreciated

Thank you

nickzde

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the system in the form $$ Xw = y $$
i.e. (note each series is in a column of $X$)
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 3 & 8 \\
4 & 1 & 0 \\
9 & 8 & 6 \\
1 & 6 & 0 \\
7 & 2 & 9 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
 w_1 \\ w_2 \\ w_3
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
 90 \\ 60 \\ 70 \\ 21 \\ 45
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now to solve for $w,$ you can approximate it using [least-squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares) as follows:
$$
Aw = y \\
A^{T} A w = A^{T} y \\
w = (A^{T} A)^{-1} A^{T} y \\
$$
This will work as long as $A^{T} A$ is invertible.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer. And how to resolve it in the case when A^{T}A is not invertible? Thank you

Comment: When $A^{T}A$ is not invertible this means that one series is an exact multiple of some other series. Remove the redundant one are proceed.

Comment: Now I see. Could I have an additional question please? As least-squares gives me an approximation, it can happen that result of multiplication of resulting w value with X will be smaller than intended value y. Is there a way how to make every w big enough so that Xw >= y? And is it possible, at the same time, to make sure every Xw <= some other number? Many Thanks again! I am marking your reply as answer.

Comment: @hugo I am not quite sure. AFAIK, least squares minimizes [the *square* of the error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_mean_square_error). In other words it minimizes $(Aw - y)^2.$ So it can give you $Aw$ bigger or smaller than $y.$ Think $(2.1-2)^2$ is small. Also $(1.9-2)^2$ is small. What you need is minimize the error (not squared). I have to go through my course notes to recall which method. But please go ahead and post a new question; maybe someone else know readily.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have posted new question [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126992/set-boundary-for-least-square-calculation). We can meet there again :) Have a nice day.hugo

Answer (score 0):

Let say you multiply the rows by $a,b$ and $c$, respectively. Then if you add them up you get the following system of equations $2a+3b+8c=90$, $4a+1b+0=60$, $9a+8b+6c=70$, $1a+6b+0c=21$  and $7a+2b+9c=45$. You can solve the system of equations as usual.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer. Is it possible to alter these equations> 2a+3b+8c=90 ...etc. in such a way they would implement not only a,b,c but also d,e,f.....in the case there was more series than just 3? Again many thanks.